# Intervals specified according to column values in PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

My Data is like this

```
wavelength    reflectance
341.6         2.48
343.6         2.58
347.6         4.51
351.1         8.51
359.2         9.56
362.2         11.2
364.2         25.3
365.3         58.2
366.6         58.2
368.9         24.2
373.6         28.2
```

I wish to take 10 intervals of wavelength and the reflectance intervals in between them is taken average then the output will be
**I want output like this**

```
wavelength    reflectnce
341.6         2.48
351.1         5.20
362.2         10.38
373.6         32.35
```

Comment: Er, what? I'm not sure how you're getting from the input to the output.

Comment: can you describe what is the relation between your table and your result?

Comment: the relation is that if i give 10 intervals. the output will be displayed according to shown above, If you seen the data, the interval if i provide 10 it is taking the interval values according to wavelength, and then the corresponding reflectance values of the wavelength[inteval size is varied for every 10 ]

Comment: In your sample output the wavelengths are not exactly 10 apart. The intervals are 9.5, 11.1, 11.4. Do you mean each wavelength should be "the next one which is closest to 10 greater than the previous one"?

Comment: yes each wavelength should be selected or before one which is closest to 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server you can do it like this:

```
;WITH CTE AS(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(wavelength AS INT)-CAST(wavelength AS INT)%10 ORDER BY wavelength) AS ROW_ID,wavelength,reflectance FROM Your_Table
)

SELECT wavelength,reflectance FROM CTE WHERE ROW_ID=1
```

Hope it would help.

Comment: Suraj thanks, it is very related to me, but it showing some intervals not according to 10, if u want i will send the data to u...

Comment: Could you please share the scenario in which it is not working as expected.

Comment: 341.6;2.66
349.5;2.45
360.5;2.48
369.9;2.50
380.8;2.53
390.1;2.75
401.0;2.95
410.2;3.33
420.9;3.71
430.1;4.00
440.8;4.06
449.9;4.30
460.5;4.34
469.6;4.55
480.1;4.56
490.7;4.61
499.6;5.02
510.1;5.77
520.5;7.21
530.9;8.87
539.8;9.69
550.1;9.88
560.4;10.01
570.6;9.58
580.9;8.59
589.6;8.07
599.7;7.82
609.8;7.71
619.8;7.28
629.8;6.93
639.7;6.63
649.6;6.28
660.8;6.06
670.6;5.87
680.3;6.39
689.9;8.14
699.5;11.71
710.4;17.73
719.9;23.12
730.6;28.74
739.9;32.48

Comment: Got the following result with your data;

wavelength reflectance
341.6 2.66
360.5 2.48
380.8 2.53
390.1 2.75
401 2.95
410.2 3.33
420.9 3.71
430.1 4
440.8 4.06
460.5 4.34
480.1 4.56
490.7 4.61
510.1 5.77
520.5 7.21
530.9 8.87
550.1 9.88
560.4 10.01
570.6 9.58
580.9 8.59
599.7 7.82
609.8 7.71
619.8 7.28
629.8 6.93
639.7 6.63
649.6 6.28
660.8 6.06
670.6 5.87
680.3 6.39
699.5 11.71
710.4 17.73
730.6 28.74

Comment: Now the code you provided is correct, then i want to mean the reflectance values of the intermediate rows and the mean should be placed as the next reflectance value