# Intervals averaging on postgresql data

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

My Data is like this

```
wavelength    reflectance
341.6         2.48
343.6         2.58
347.6         4.51
351.1         8.51
359.2         9.56
362.2         11.2
364.2         25.3
365.3         58.2
366.6         58.2
368.9         24.2
373.6         28.2
```

I wish to take 10 intervals of wavelength and the reflectance intervals in between them is taken average then the output will be `I want output like this`

```
wavelength    reflectnce
341.6         2.48
351.1         5.20
362.2         10.38
373.6         32.35
```

If i am using this code it is displaying wavelength intervals fine. now i want to average the reflectance intervals inbetween them and i will put it on next row reflectance

```
    ;WITH CTE AS(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(wavelength AS INT)-CAST(wavelength AS INT)%10 ORDER BY wavelength) AS ROW_ID,wavelength,reflectance FROM Your_Table
)

SELECT wavelength,reflectance FROM CTE WHERE ROW_ID=1
```

If anyone knows, Please help me...

Comment: Didn't you ask this before, then ignore follow-up questions?

Comment: i am using this code it only take up intervals of wavelength but the reflectance is calculated based on average of inbetween reflectance values

Comment: For context, previous question appears to be http://stackoverflow.com/q/22032995/398670. Comments there may be informative.

Comment: it is the same data but i'm applying formulas now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking something like this --> [demo (click me please)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1f716/39)

```
WITH CTE AS(
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
    PARTITION BY CAST(wavelength AS INT)
                 -CAST(wavelength AS INT)%10 
    ORDER BY wavelength) AS ROW_ID,
  wavelength,
  avg( reflectance ) OVER(
    PARTITION BY CAST(wavelength AS INT)
                 -CAST(wavelength AS INT)%10 
    ORDER BY wavelength
    rows BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING
         and UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) As reflectance 
  FROM 
  Your_Table
)
select wavelength, reflectance
from cte
where row_id = 1
```

This is a result of this query for sample data:

```
| WAVELENGTH | REFLECTANCE |
|------------|-------------|
|      341.6 |       3.545 |
|      351.1 |        9.56 |
|      362.2 |      41.475 |
|      373.6 |      (null) |
```

The calculated average doesn't include the first value,
for example for the following rows in input data:

```
wavelength    reflectance
341.6         2.48
343.6         2.58
347.6         4.51
```

avg = ( 2.58 + 4.51 ) / 2  --> the first row was skipped

Comment: in between null values can't be placed and the average of reflectance value replaces the reflectance value...just view the output i give it...

Comment: Could you show in the question what is desired result of the query for sample data, sir ?

Comment: In the desired query the average of wavelength intervals next of 341.6(i.e)343.6-351.1 the reflectance is averaged and it replace the 351.1 interval reflectance value...

Comment: if anyone wish i will send the data

Comment: I've corrected my answer, please take a look at a new query.

Comment: sir, here my first row value is changing, according to my query it will not change, Please just check once....